# LAMP management ui

Tags: linux, apache, user-interface, lamp

I'd like a system where I can manage my LAMP server. It is a real server, so it isnt a VPS. But apart from everyone else online, I dont want to sell space on it. I just want to manage it for my own purpose.

So I can change settings on the fly without accessing the Shell.

I would of course like it to be an active, either open source or free software.

Web UI is also a requirement.

As any configuration tool on various web hotels, with possibility to configure only for one mashine, and no virtual spaces or such.

Would be great, as after tons of googling I came to the conclusion that there are tons of systems and they all are too advanced or just look aweful and seem to complex.

My goals.
Manage domains,
Manage emails for domains,
Manage Apache (possibly vhosts and such)
Manage MySQL (could use phpmyadmin)
Manage logs and similar
Manage SVN (if possible)
Manage FTP

And such features, not too advanced stuff.

Much appriciated if you know any good systems of such caliber. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another could be http://isp-control.net/

And: http://www.syscp.org/

And again: http://www.ispconfig.org/

Comment: I was looking at the SysCp, is it something you would recommend? It looks extremely simple, but if it performs kind of what I need that is perfect! isp-control web page seems to be down atm

Comment: ok if i remember well i tried isp-control many years ago (at least 3 years ago, and i had several problems managing users/accounts, but in three years many things are changed, actually for my machine i use webmin). Syscp seems a good alternative, and take a look also to ispconfig.

Answer (score 2):

webmin (http://www.webmin.com/) might be what you're looking for.

Comment: I was looking at this, however their demo is in russian, I suppose someone changed the language to russian xD, and yes, I suppose it is something like this, however it seems advanced and hard to work with. I could be wrong, but that is my first thought of it.